# Pip install fails due to package requirements dependencies

Tags: python, build, pip, numba

I released a Python 3 [package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysight) to PyPI (using [this](https://github.com/ionelmc/cookiecutter-pylibrary) excellent cookiecutter template) which depends on `C` extensions written with Cython, JIT compilation with Numba and other packages dependent on Numpy and such.

When I don't specify any requirements in `requirements.txt` and\or in `install_requires` inside `setupy.py` the package installs successfully, indicating that the cookiecutter template does its job properly. Moreover, CI tools like [AppVeyor](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/HagaiHargil/python-pysight) and [Travis](https://travis-ci.org/HagaiHargil/python-pysight) can successfully build my package and test it.

However, when I type in the list of requirements, regardless of its order, `pip install` commands fails (in a naive virtual environment) and the CI tools are unable to build it as well (the error logs are visible in the links above). If I pre-install Numba on that virtual environment and then try to `pip install` everything works. This has been replicated on both Windows (10) and CentOS.

I suspect that when this issue will be solved the CI tools will also be able to build my package successfully.

Windows log:

```
C:\Users\Hagai\Documents\GitHub\python-pysight>activate py36

(py36) C:\Users\Hagai\Documents\GitHub\python-pysight>pip install pysight
Collecting pysight
  Downloading pysight-0.1.6-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl (113kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 122kB 460kB/s
Collecting attrs>=1.6 (from pysight)
  Using cached attrs-16.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting tables (from pysight)
  Using cached tables-3.3.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting pandas (from pysight)
  Using cached pandas-0.19.2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting numba (from pysight)
  Using cached numba-0.31.0.tar.gz
Collecting matplotlib (from pysight)
  Using cached matplotlib-2.0.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting tifffile (from pysight)
Collecting cython (from pysight)
Collecting numpy>=1.8.0 (from tables->pysight)
  Using cached numpy-1.12.0-cp36-none-win_amd64.whl
Collecting numexpr>=2.5.2 (from tables->pysight)
  Using cached numexpr-2.6.2-cp36-none-win_amd64.whl
Collecting six (from tables->pysight)
  Using cached six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pytz>=2011k (from pandas->pysight)
  Using cached pytz-2016.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting python-dateutil>=2 (from pandas->pysight)
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting llvmlite (from numba->pysight)
  Using cached llvmlite-0.16.0.tar.gz
Collecting cycler>=0.10 (from matplotlib->pysight)
  Using cached cycler-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=1.5.6 (from matplotlib->pysight)
  Using cached pyparsing-2.1.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: numba, llvmlite
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for numba ... error
  Complete output from command C:\Users\Hagai\Anaconda3\envs\py36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Hagai\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-ry0rxpw8\\numba\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\Hagai\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpd75ai9dzpip-wheel- --python-tag cp36:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\Hagai\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ry0rxpw8\numba\setup.py", line 250, in <module>
      metadata['ext_modules'] = get_ext_modules()
    File "C:\Users\Hagai\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ry0rxpw8\numba\setup.py", line 82, in get_ext_modules
      import numpy.distutils.misc_util as np_misc
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for numba
  Running setup.py clean for numba
  Complete output from command C:\Users\Hagai\Anaconda3\envs\py36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Hagai\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-ry0rxpw8\\numba\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" clean --all:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\Hagai\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ry0rxpw8\numba\setup.py", line 250, in <module>
      metadata['ext_modules'] = get_ext_modules()
    File "C:\Users\Hagai\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ry0rxpw8\numba\setup.py", line 82, in get_ext_modules
      import numpy.distutils.misc_util as np_misc
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed cleaning build dir for numba
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for llvmlite ... error
  Complete output from command C:\Users\Hagai\Anaconda3\envs\py36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Hagai\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-ry0rxpw8\\llvmlite\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\Hagai\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpcioz28cjpip-wheel- --python-tag cp36:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  got version from file C:\Users\Hagai\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ry0rxpw8\llvmlite\llvmlite/_version.py {'version': '0.16.0', 'full': '964cf1d6d725b000c769379a5efe11932fcfc551'}
  running build_ext
  C:\Users\Hagai\Anaconda3\envs\py36\python.exe C:\Users\Hagai\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ry0rxpw8\llvmlite\ffi\build.py
  Trying generator 'Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64'
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Hagai\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ry0rxpw8\llvmlite\ffi\build.py", line 152, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\Users\Hagai\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ry0rxpw8\llvmlite\ffi\build.py", line 140, in main
      main_win32()
    File "C:\Users\Hagai\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ry0rxpw8\llvmlite\ffi\build.py", line 74, in main_win32
      generator = find_win32_generator()
    File "C:\Users\Hagai\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ry0rxpw8\llvmlite\ffi\build.py", line 62, in find_win32_generator
      try_cmake(cmake_dir, build_dir, generator)
    File "C:\Users\Hagai\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ry0rxpw8\llvmlite\ffi\build.py", line 27, in try_cmake
      subprocess.check_call(['cmake', '-G', generator, cmake_dir])
    File "C:\Users\Hagai\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\subprocess.py", line 286, in check_call
      retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\Hagai\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\subprocess.py", line 267, in call
      with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
    File "C:\Users\Hagai\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
      restore_signals, start_new_session)
    File "C:\Users\Hagai\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\subprocess.py", line 990, in _execute_child
      startupinfo)
  FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
  error: command 'C:\\Users\\Hagai\\Anaconda3\\envs\\py36\\python.exe' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for llvmlite
  Running setup.py clean for llvmlite
Failed to build numba llvmlite
Installing collected packages: attrs, numpy, numexpr, six, tables, pytz, python-dateutil, pandas, llvmlite, numba, cycler, pyparsing, matplotlib, tifffile, cython, pysight
  Running setup.py install for llvmlite ... error
    Complete output from command C:\Users\Hagai\Anaconda3\envs\py36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Hagai\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-ry0rxpw8\\llvmlite\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Hagai\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-9a1uhuys-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    got version from file C:\Users\Hagai\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ry0rxpw8\llvmlite\llvmlite/_version.py {'version': '0.16.0', 'full': '964cf1d6d725b000c769379a5efe11932fcfc551'}
    running build_ext
    C:\Users\Hagai\Anaconda3\envs\py36\python.exe C:\Users\Hagai\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ry0rxpw8\llvmlite\ffi\build.py
    Trying generator 'Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Hagai\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ry0rxpw8\llvmlite\ffi\build.py", line 152, in <module>
        main()
      File "C:\Users\Hagai\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ry0rxpw8\llvmlite\ffi\build.py", line 140, in main
        main_win32()
      File "C:\Users\Hagai\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ry0rxpw8\llvmlite\ffi\build.py", line 74, in main_win32
        generator = find_win32_generator()
      File "C:\Users\Hagai\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ry0rxpw8\llvmlite\ffi\build.py", line 62, in find_win32_generator
        try_cmake(cmake_dir, build_dir, generator)
      File "C:\Users\Hagai\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ry0rxpw8\llvmlite\ffi\build.py", line 27, in try_cmake
        subprocess.check_call(['cmake', '-G', generator, cmake_dir])
      File "C:\Users\Hagai\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\subprocess.py", line 286, in check_call
        retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Hagai\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\subprocess.py", line 267, in call
        with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
      File "C:\Users\Hagai\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
        restore_signals, start_new_session)
      File "C:\Users\Hagai\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\subprocess.py", line 990, in _execute_child
        startupinfo)
    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
    error: command 'C:\\Users\\Hagai\\Anaconda3\\envs\\py36\\python.exe' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Users\Hagai\Anaconda3\envs\py36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Hagai\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-ry0rxpw8\\llvmlite\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Hagai\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-9a1uhuys-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Hagai\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ry0rxpw8\llvmlite\
```

CentOS log:

```
  File "/tmp/easy_install-x7jp8trx/numba-0.31.0/setup.py", line 250, in <module>
  File "/tmp/easy_install-x7jp8trx/numba-0.31.0/setup.py", line 82, in get_ext_modules
    'matplotlib',
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-qkv60_2c/pysight/setup.py", line 104, in <module>
    for root, _, _ in os.walk('src')
  File "/opt/anaconda/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 108, in setup
    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
  File "/opt/anaconda/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 315, in __init__
  File "/opt/anaconda/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 361, in fetch_build_eggs
  File "/opt/anaconda/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 851, in resolve
  File "/opt/anaconda/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1123, in best_match
  File "/opt/anaconda/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1135, in obtain
  File "/opt/anaconda/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 428, in fetch_build_egg
  File "/opt/anaconda/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 664, in easy_install
  File "/opt/anaconda/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 694, in install_item
  File "/opt/anaconda/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 875, in install_eggs
  File "/opt/anaconda/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1114, in build_and_install
  File "/opt/anaconda/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1100, in run_setup
  File "/opt/anaconda/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 249, in run_setup
  File "/opt/anaconda/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 100, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/opt/anaconda/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 197, in setup_context
  File "/opt/anaconda/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 100, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/opt/anaconda/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 168, in save_modules
  File "/opt/anaconda/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 143, in resume
  File "/opt/anaconda/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg/pkg_resources/_vendor/six.py", line 685, in reraise
  File "/opt/anaconda/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 156, in save_modules
  File "/opt/anaconda/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 197, in setup_context
  File "/opt/anaconda/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 246, in run_setup
  File "/opt/anaconda/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 276, in run
  File "/opt/anaconda/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 245, in runner
  File "/opt/anaconda/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 47, in _execfile
  File "/tmp/easy_install-x7jp8trx/numba-0.31.0/setup.py", line 250, in <module>
  File "/tmp/easy_install-x7jp8trx/numba-0.31.0/setup.py", line 82, in get_ext_modules
    'matplotlib',
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Comment: Hey HagaiH, can you include the full pip output?  What happens if you add  `numpy` to install_requires https://github.com/HagaiHargil/python-pysight/blob/master/setup.py ?

Comment: Hi, I've added the full Windows log. I tried adding `numpy` explicitly into the mix to no avail. It gives the same error.

Comment: It's interesting.  Numba is very clearly being installed first and it depends on numpy in it's setup.py so the install fails.  Try adding numpy to setup_requires as well.

Comment: I think it's a little odd to have numba in both `setup_requires` and `install_requires` as well.  Typically if you need it to run your package it should be in `install_requires`.  In general,    `setup_requires` is primarily for packages that are only required to install the rest of the software and then they can be removed.

Comment: I just pushed a new update (version 0.1.7) with `numpy` in the `setup_requires` part of `setup.py`, and unfortunately a similar, but slightly different, error occurs. 
http://pastebin.com/0Zn15p4c

Comment: It seems like environmental: "FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
  error: command 'C:\\Users\\Hagai\\Anaconda3\\envs\\py36\\python.exe' failed with exit status 1".  Does that exe exist?  Does this build on another platform (Travis ci?)

Comment: Yes, it's there. `pip install numba` didn't work for me either, but `conda install numba` did work. It might be an internal issue of Numba.